# Postgres: Get just variable names

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres, how can I create a list of variable names of a table? I don't want to read in the whole table, I just want to get the variable names. Thanks!

Comment: Tables don't have "variables". Do you maybe mean *columns*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres (and other RDBMSs) exposes the structure of your database through the information schema. You can query it like you would anything else:

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'public' and table_name = 'mytable'
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!